# Passing multiple values from SQL Server Agent to SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have 4 values that I need to pass from a SQL server Agent Job into my SSIS package. 
Here is my code from the CommandLine.

(line breaks added for readability)

```
/SQL "\"\DataWarehouse\Common\SSISPackageExecution\"" 
/SERVER "\"DEV-DS12\""  
/CHECKPOINTING OFF 
/SET "\"\Package.Variables[Control::SQLAgentJob].Value\"";"\"\"\"SSIS - Data Warehouse ETL\"\"\"" 
/SET "\"\Package.Variables[Control::Category].Value\"";"\"\"\"Dimension\"\"\"" 
/SET "\"\Package.Variables[Control::StartStep].Value\"";"\"\"\"10\"\"\"" 
/SET "\"\Package.Variables[Control::EndStep].Value\"";"\"\"\"20\\\"\"\"" 
/REPORTING E
```

I am working with SQL Server 2014, SSMS 2014, and VS 13 with 2014 datatools

When I execute my Job is gives me this: 
 Option "-" is not valid.  The command line parameters are invalid.

My Property Paths are:

- \Package.Variables[Control::SQLAgentJob].Value
- \Package.Variables[Control::Category].Value
- \Package.Variables[Control::StartStep].Value
- \Package.Variables[Control::EndStep].Value

My Values are:

- "SSIS - Data Warehouse ETL"
- "Dimension"
- "10"
- "20"

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quote escaping:

```
/SQL "\DataWarehouse\Common\SSISPackageExecution" 
/SERVER "DEV-DS12"  
/CHECKPOINTING OFF 
/SET "Package.Variables[Control::SQLAgentJob].Value";"SSIS - Data Warehouse ETL" 
/SET "Package.Variables[Control::Category].Value";"Dimension" 
/SET "Package.Variables[Control::StartStep].Value";"10" 
/SET "Package.Variables[Control::EndStep].Value";"20" 
/REPORTING E
```

Comment: Looks much better to me and the way I would have written it. So I should just manually edit the command line to make this edit, correct? Since I was just adding the data to the tabs.